# F# - How to create an async function dynamically based on return type

Tags: reflection, f#, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a function dynamically that can return different types based on it's input in F#. These types of functions are like proxies, to illustrate what I am trying to do, here follows an example that is *not* working correctly:

```
open FSharp.Reflection
open System

let functionThatReturnsAsync (irrelevantArgs: obj list) (returnType: Type) = 
    if returnType.GUID = typeof<string>.GUID
    then async { return box "some text" } 
    elif returnType.GUID = typeof<int>.GUID
    then async { return box 42 }
    elif returnType.GUID = typeof<bool>.GUID
    then async { return box true }
    else async { return box null }

// this works fine
let func = FSharpValue.MakeFunction(typeof<string -> Async<int>>, fun x -> box (functionThatReturnsAsync [x] typeof<int>))

// unboxing to that type works as well
let fn = unbox<string -> Async<int>> func 

async {
    // HERE THE ERROR
    let! output = fn "hello"
    printfn "%d" output
}
|> Async.StartImmediate
```

When I invoke `fn` it seem to be trying to cast `FSharpFunc<string, FSharpAsync<obj>>` to `FSharpFunc<string, FSharpAsync<int>>` but the cast is invalid. Even without the `async` CE, just invoking `fn` to get the async value fails:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+IntrinsicFunctions.UnboxGeneric[T] (System.Object source) [0x00018] in<5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Reflect+Invoke@820-4[T1,T2].Invoke (T1 inp) [0x00011] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at FSI_0019+it@182-10.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x0000a] in <a19bbccfdeb3402381709b6f2e8ef105>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+callA@522[b,a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncParams`1[T] args) [0x00051] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <9bbab8f8a2a246e98480e70b0839fd67>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control+StartImmediate@1223-1.Invoke (System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo edi) [0x00000] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps+StartWithContinuations@964-1.Invoke (System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo x) [0x00000] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+callA@522[b,a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncParams`1[T] args) [0x00103] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+startAsync@430[a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) [0x00033] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Control.loop@124-50 (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline this, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] action) [0x00000] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.ExecuteAction (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] firstAction) [0x00017] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.TrampolineHolder.Protect (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] firstAction) [0x00031] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.startAsync[a] (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] cont, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] econt, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] ccont, Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] p) [0x00013] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CancellationTokenOps.StartWithContinuations[T] (System.Threading.CancellationToken token, Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] a, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] cont, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] econt, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] ccont) [0x00014] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync.StartImmediate (Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[T] computation, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] cancellationToken) [0x0002b] in <5ac785a3dff9fae1a7450383a385c75a>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0019>.$FSI_0019.main@ () [0x00019] in <a19bbccfdeb3402381709b6f2e8ef105>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <9bbab8f8a2a246e98480e70b0839fd67>:0
Stopped due to error
```

Is this even possible and to make the example work? I don't mind even fiddling with IL emits to get this working but I am not sure how. If something is unclear about the question, let me know and I will update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can leverage generics as Aaron suggests, then doing that will be a better idea. However, if you need to choose a type at runtime, then you can make your code work by changing `functionThatReturnsAsync` to look as follows:

```
let functionThatReturnsAsync (irrelevantArgs: obj list) (returnType: Type) = 
    if returnType.GUID = typeof<string>.GUID
    then box (async { return "some text" })
    elif returnType.GUID = typeof<int>.GUID
    then box (async { return 42 })
    elif returnType.GUID = typeof<bool>.GUID
    then box (async { return true })
    else box (async { return (null:obj) })
```

This is almost the same as what you had - but rather than boxing the values *inside* async computations, it is boxing the whole async computation (which then returns the value of the right type) - so the casting works!

Comment: The problem is, the returned value inside the async is always boxed as obj, I am getting the value from JSON and deserializing dynamically to the correct `returnType`, so I think because of that, even boxing the whole async didn't solve the problem.  If only there were an non-generic `unbox(t: Type, o: obj)` that I could use but I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: @ZaidAjaj It's a bit difficult to imagine what the concrete scenario is - could you post a new question with code that demonstrates the aspect that was not solved by this answer?

Comment: I was trying to create a record dynamically as a proxy object with each field that is function, providing the implementation of each function based on the input and output types.  The implementation is a POST request that deserialises the JSON result to the correct return type of the respective function. Using reflection seems too difficult and needs too many hacks around the runtime to get it to work, I resorted to quotations and got an elegant solution, I will post the results (code before/after) when I publish the code because it is in some commit in the history, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I would do this by leveraging generics, instead of trying to dynamically create a function.  Here's your code, modified to take advantage of generic types instead:

```
open FSharp.Reflection
open System

let functionThatReturnsAsync<'a> (irrelevantArgs: obj list) = 
    match Unchecked.defaultof<'a> |> box with
    | :? Guid -> async { return box "some text" } 
    | :? Int32 -> async { return box 42 }
    | :? Boolean -> async { return box true }
    | _ -> async { return box null }


// unboxing to that type works as well
let fn<'a> input = 
    async {    
        let! result = functionThatReturnsAsync<'a> [input |> box]
        return result |> unbox<'a>
    }

// This works now
async {
    let! output = fn<int> "hello"
    printfn "%d" output
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: I think my example was an oversimplification of my original problem, all the function types you see at only available at runtime so `result |> unbox<'a>` won't work, I was looking for a non-generic version of it but didn't find any